# Application to track internet activity

Tags: internet, tracking

I don't have any anti virus installed in my machine, I have only firewall installed in my machine. Some program is trying to connect internet and download something. I don't know which application is trying to connect to internet.

Is there any application so that i can track all internet usage.

For Example:
 So i can get information like
This application "ABC.exe" accessed internet at this time downloaded this much KB or uploaded this much KB.

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer opensource application due to cost constaints

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why on earth are you running with no anti virus?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson - I assume Windows because of the reference to a .exe file

Comment: OS Windows XP. Is there any Anti virus freely available?

Comment: moreover i don't believe in Anti virus

Comment: @Soft - AVG is free (http://free.avg.com). Surely something is better than nothing..........?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that was my assumption also, however my point is to the OP that the question should be more specific so we don't have to make assumptions.

Comment: Why don't you believe in antivirus?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running Windows, many third-party firewalls work on the application level, that is, if you set them to work in the proper mode, when any application attempts to connect to the Internet, you will be notified with a pop-up and given an opportunity to accept or reject it.

I use Comodo for this purpose on Windows, and it has a free version that can be configured to work like this.  I'm sure ZoneAlarm and others will do this to.  I know Comodo can be configured to generate logs as well.

If you already have a firewall installed, read its documentation, it may already have this capability.

Note that on Windows, just knowing the executable name might not be enough information.  Particularly problematic are "rundll32.exe" and "svchost.exe."  You might still have to do some digging and research even with that information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use ZoneAlarm (free version). It do have a log. It asks for permission whether to access internet or not. The problem is sometimes the application i am giving access to the internet is not trusted. That application connects to internet independently.